# WCF web application: global.aspx

Tags: c#, wcf

We have self hosted a group of WCF services in a WCf web application.

If we put code calls in the global.Application_Start() and the server or IIS is restarted, will the first service need to be hit for the 'Start' to start? Or will it start when IIS restarts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application_Start will be called only at the first access to that web application(either a service call or a visited web page); a Windows Server restart or an IIS restart or App Pool recycle will not call it for you.